# how to append next line(break line) while parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am doing following parsing in objective c.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if (!_chars) {
    _chars = [string mutableCopy];
  } else {
    [_chars appendString:string];

     [_chars appendString:break line??];
  }
}
```

i want to append or break line after every string found. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[_chars appendString:@"\n"];
```

Should add new line.

Answer (score 0):

`@"\n"`

That should do it just fine i recon